# Get horizontal header section size

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for a function that returns the width of a QTableWidget horizontal header: after a deep research in the official documentation, the only thing I've found is [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#defaultSectionSize-prop), but the debugger send me this error at the line:

```
int section = table->horizontalHeader()->defaultSectionSize();
```

> error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QHeaderView'

Of course, I specified the ResizeMode in the constructor:

```
table->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Interactive);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Introduction

`QTableView::horizontalHeader` is declared to return a pointer to a `QHeaderView`, the problem is that the definition of what this pointer refers to isn't declared in `<QTableWidget>` (more specifically in `<QTableView>`, which *QTableWidget* includes); it's merely [forward declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757718/1090079).

The compiler is telling you that you are trying to use an *incomplete type*, meaning that the compiler doesn't know the definition of said type.

Having a pointer to an *incomplete type* is fine, but you are not allowed (and cannot) to access anything inside it.

---

#### Solution

The full declaration of `QHeaderView` is available in `<QHeaderView>`, include it and the compiler will be satisfied.

```
#include <QHeaderView> // <- required
```